# How to find man pages for C structs (struct sockaddr_in)?

Tags: c, linux, struct, manpage

I am having a hard time finding man pages for the structures used in socket. So I am currently learning about them from a separate online tutorial. But it would be nice to know how to lookup these structures in the man pages itself.

I am using a Debian 8.3 Linux system.

For example, I found information about `struct addrinfo` in `man getaddrinfo`.

But I have not been able to find information about `struct sockaddr_in` in any man page. Which man page contains the details about this struct? And how to find out the man pages for such structures in general?

Comment: google is your friend (very complex "struct sockaddr_in" search keywords): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find that specific structure by typing `man 7 ip` and then searching manually for it or pressing <kbd>/</kbd> and typing `sockaddr_in`.

If you don't know what section to look in you can try using a quick search with `man -k sockaddr_in`. If that doesn't give you the result you are looking for try brute-forcing it with `man -K sockaddr_in`, this might be very slow because it will scan *all* the man files on your system.

@Jean-FrançoisFabre his comment about using a search engine is probably the fastest way to find the information you want though.

Comment: I type `man -k sockaddr` but result is `sockaddr: nothing appropriate.`. But `socksddr` is located in `man bind`.